# What is the simplest way to link a SVG file created in Illustrator to my html and give it hover effects?

Tags: html, css, svg

I've explored a few options such as using the object or svg tag. However I am confused as to how to link my SVG file into the html and then use CSS to animate it.

Here is an example of my code

```
<div class="pull-left m-l-20 m-t-10 h3 inline-block">
    <svg id="lnkLeft" class="c-dark"></svg>
</div>
```

Is it possible to use the SVG tag and link the image file in there and then animate using the class in CSS?

Comment: Try these techniques:

https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, you can style SVGs with CSS, **to an extent**.

The svg **must** be used as an *inline* svg, rather than in an `<img>` or `background-image`:

```
<svg id="lnkLeft" class="c-dark"></svg>
```

Then you can style it directly through CSS by either targetting `.c-dark` or `svg` directly. Keep in mind that if you want to change the colour of the SVG on hover, you're actually looking for the `fill` attribute, rather than the traditional `color`:

```
.c-dark:hover {
    fill: #FFF;
}
```

Due to SVG files often taking up a *lot* of lines, this can get quite ugly in your HTML. However, if you have access to PHP, you can actually output the SVG with `file_get_contents`:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents("image.svg"); ?>
```

This will render the SVG on the page directly, so you can target it with CSS.

Keep in mind that if you were to link to it in an `<img>` tag (or use it as a **background-image**) you won't be able to style it through CSS!

For further reading, check out CSS' tricks' articles [here](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/) and [here](https://css-tricks.com/cascading-svg-fill-color/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful!